# Referring to resource files in Spring application.properties

Tags: spring, properties

I have a spring project with a POM file which has a fragment as below -

```
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
                <webResources>
                    <resource>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/webapp/WEB-INF</directory>
                        <filtering>true</filtering>
                        <targetPath>WEB-INF</targetPath>
                        <includes>
                            <include>**/*.csv</include>
                        </includes>
                    </resource>
                </webResources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
```

My source directory src/main/webapp has a csv file called myfile.csv.

On doing a mvn clean install, this csv file gets stored in my target/myproject-0.2.0-SNAPSHOT directory.

What string do I need to use in application.properties file to reach the location of this file? Will this value also apply when the app is deployed as a war file. Also, ideally, should resources go under WEB-INF directory and if yes, what do I need to change in my POM file.

Answer (score 0):

Copy the files to WEB-INF/classes. After that they should be available on classpath

```
this.getClass().getResourceAsStream("/SomeTextFile.csv");
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. So in application.properties file, can I simply use this - myfile.path = /someTextFile.csv ?